# I am getting this error -> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file

Tags: android, xml

I am developing an app which is showing  the following log cat result.. it mentions a binary xml file.. the problem is there is no file in my system with such name... so which is the file that is mentioned in the log cat???

```
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thomas/com.quinoid.thomas.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at com.quinoid.thomas.Home.onCreate(Home.java:12)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     ... 11 more
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791): Caused by:      java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     ... 24 more
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
 06-04 07:05:29.080: E/AndroidRuntime(791):     ... 27 more
 06-04 07:05:31.420: I/Process(791): Sending signal. PID: 791 SIG: 9
```

the on click image swapping happens without any issue.. the on click is not occurring.. the app is crashing there... 
this is the source code :

```
     public class HomePage extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_page);
        main();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void main() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        final Button home;
        final Button aboutus;
        final Button contacts;
        final Button clients;
        final Button services;
        try
        {

        home = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
        aboutus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAboutus);
        clients = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClients);
        contacts = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnContacts);
        services = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnServices);

        home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                home.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home1);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomePage.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        aboutus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                aboutus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.about1);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomePage.this, AboutUs.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        clients.setOnClickListener(new  OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                clients.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clients1);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomePage.this, Clients.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        contacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                contacts.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.contacts1);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomePage.this, Contacts.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        services.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                services.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.services1);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomePage.this, Services.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

layout file...

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@drawable/withoutlogo">    

 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
     android:layout_width="206.38dp"
     android:layout_height="340dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
     android:background="@drawable/arcrail" >

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnHome"
         android:layout_width="108dp"
         android:layout_height="36dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:background="@drawable/home" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnContacts"
         android:layout_width="108dp"
         android:layout_height="36dp"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:background="@drawable/contacts" />

 </RelativeLayout>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnServices"
     android:layout_width="117dp"
     android:layout_height="39dp"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnAboutus"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnAboutus"
     android:layout_marginBottom="-80dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="-22.25dp"
     android:background="@drawable/services" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnAboutus"
     android:layout_width="117dp"
     android:layout_height="39dp"
     android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout1"
     android:layout_marginBottom="-110dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="-75dp"
     android:background="@drawable/about" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnClients"
       android:layout_width="117dp"
       android:layout_height="39dp"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnAboutus"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnAboutus"
       android:layout_marginBottom="-160dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="-04dp"
       android:background="@drawable/clients" />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="140dp"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:src="@drawable/header1" />
```

logcat on button press (am not using any sound files with this)

```
 06-05 01:01:46.323: W/EGL_emulation(1191): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
 06-05 01:01:54.283: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.283: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.283: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.283: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.293: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.293: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.293: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.293: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.293: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.293: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.293: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.293: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.303: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.303: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.303: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.303: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.303: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.303: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.303: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.303: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
 06-05 01:01:54.303: W/AudioService(382): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
 06-05 01:01:54.323: I/ActivityManager(382): START u0 {cmp=com.example.thomas/com.quinoid.thomas.Services} from pid 1191
 06-05 01:01:54.583: W/EGL_emulation(1191): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
 06-05 01:01:57.033: I/ActivityManager(382): Displayed com.example.thomas/com.quinoid.thomas.Services: +2s658ms
```

Comment: Post your layout.xml file.

Comment: Problem is with your layout xml file. Post it.

Comment: @SimplePlan layout file posted

Comment: @user3214173 post your all activity code where you load this layout

Comment: have you try clean and build the project again?if not try this

Comment: Binary XML file line #8: check for this line number in your xml

Comment: @user1969053 yes.. i dont have a file named binary xml file...

Comment: @ Kat-hat yep more than 20 times.. been woking on this since yesterday..

Comment: @user3214173 let me clear one thing why are you load `home_page` as `layout` ? is it really a `layout` or a `Menu xml` file? if it's layout then why are you load as `Menu` in your `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_page, menu);`

Comment: @user3214173 Binary Xml file is the layout file that you are inflating in your activity.

Comment: just check any images name should be wrong

Comment: all image names are correct.. peter.. and home_page has a menu inflator.. its only provided in the end of the code.. @Simple Plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Where is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

because the image you are using as a background of your inflator layout is  of big size(in MB's),that why it gives you out of memory error,and the system is not able to inflate that,thats why you are getting inflate exception.

## solution

```
just make that image in KB's and you will get out of this problem.
```

## Also Change:

```
src to background of your imageview in your xml.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using such big images then you should not directly infalte images,rather than use BitmapFactory  and then release previous bitmap before inflating any new images.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
    int tempWidth = -1;
    int tempHeight = -1;
    options.inSampleSize = 1;

    //calculating sample size
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    try {
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath().toString(), options);
tempWidth = options.outWidth;
    tempHeight = options.outHeight;
    LogUtil.info(TAG, "tempWidth is " + tempWidth);
    LogUtil.info(TAG, "tempHeight is " + tempHeight);
    while (tempWidth > MAX_LIMIT_EDGE || tempHeight > MAX_LIMIT_EDGE)
    {
        options.inSampleSize *= 2;
        tempWidth /= 2;
        tempHeight /= 2;
    }

    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
    {
        return null;
    }

do
    {
        if (isOutOfMemoryOccured)
        {
            options.inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
        try
        {
            imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath().toString(), options);
            isOutOfMemoryOccured = false;
        }
        catch (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError e)
        {
            LogUtil.info(TAG, "Out of memory occurred to sample size");
            isOutOfMemoryOccured = true;
        }
    }while (isOutOfMemoryOccured);
```

Then return bitmap and infalte wherever u want

and after this before infalting new resource jst call

```
bitmap.recycle();
```

Comment: the on click image swapping happens without any issue.. the on click is not occurring.. the app is crashing there... @user1969053

Comment: @user3214173 can u explain all the steps starting from launching tha app  and when u get the error

Answer (score 0):

In manifest under application tag set android:largeHeap="true". Android default allow 16 MB for application running with help of this you can increase your heap size upto 24 MB.

Comment: not a good suggestion. Large heap more frequent garbage collection. According to the docs never use large heap just because you run into OOM.

Comment: other option is to use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 250, 150, true); with help of this he can minimize bitmap size and OOM error will resolved.

Comment: @chet so the issue was system reserving small soze for the app?? but my app size is only 400kb? why does it require 24mb of memory to run?? and its only static..

Comment: bez ur are inflating that view again and again so app heap size increase continuously.see your log cat it will explain how your app size increase at run by loading large images.

Comment: not a good solution .just assigning more heap size to your app which never recommended..

Comment: so what can i do?? how can i circumvent this issue? @chet's

Comment: hv u tried with decreasing image size or try like Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length)
image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 300, 300, true));